# Android SQLite3 add Oldvalue + NewValue

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to modify value of `enabled_input_method` in android `settings.db`
table looklike this

```
=====================
ID  NAME    VALUE
=====================
1   emp     a1:a2
```

i want to add a3 value, so inside emp value will shown **a1:a2:a3**

if i run command

```
UPDATE secure SET value='a3' where name='emp'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO secure (name, value) VALUES('emp','a3');
```

it only change value to a3 and replacing the old one.

i want to know if it posibble to add record in it without typing whole old + new value?

Comment: try something like `UPDATE secure SET value=value + 'a3' `. Same as in Java to concatenate strings

Comment: have you tried this ?db.execSQL("UPDATE secure SET VALUE ='a1:a2:a3' WHERE id=1 ");

Comment: value + will return value into 1